# I cannot optimize the design for the mobile version

Tags: reactjs

There is my code. I try to change styles through props but nothing comes out, I do it to optimize the design for phones.

On Navbar.jsx

```
import { Search, ShoppingCartOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Badge } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { mobile } from "../pages/responsive";

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 60px;
  ${mobile({ height: "50px" })}
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  ${mobile({ padding: "10px 0px" })}
`;
const Left = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Language = styled.span`
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  ${mobile({ display: "none" })}
`;
```

On responsive.jsx

```
    import {cssx from "styled-components"

export const mobile = (props) => {
    return css `
        @media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
            ${props}
    }
    `;
};
```

Styles do not change, maybe I spelled the props wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a media query. The query can be adjusted to look out for a specific size (`380px`), or certain breakpoints (`lg`, `md`, etc.).

**All-in-one external library:**

[useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/) from MUI is easy to use and reliable. Below is a simple example that is watching for `380px` screen size.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery'

export default function SimpleMediaQuery()
{
  const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:380px)')

  return <span>{`(min-width:380px) matches: ${matches}`}</span>
}
```

Want to use the preset breakpoints instead?

```
const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('sm'))
```

Callback?

```
const matches = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.up('sm'))
```

This hook can be customized in multiple ways (see the docs linked above for more examples).

---

**Custom hook with no external libraries:**

If you want to do it without relying on an external library, here is a simple hook that watches for certain breakpoints, similar to MUI's `useMediaQuery`.

```
export const useMediaQuery = (width) =>
{
  const [targetReached, setTargetReached] = useState(false)

  const updateTarget = useCallback((e) =>
  {
    if (e.matches) setTargetReached(true)
    else setTargetReached(false)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    const media = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${width}px)`)
    media.addEventListener('change', updateTarget)

    // Check on mount (callback is not called until a change occurs)
    if (media.matches) setTargetReached(true)

    return () => media.removeEventListener('change', updateTarget)
  }, [])

  return targetReached
}
```

Usage:

```
// 380px
const matches = useMediaQuery(380)
```